# Terminal not accepting input

Tags: 14.04

My terminal is not accepting any input for my password as a result im unable to get any work done for some time now...... any help would be really appreciated.Thank You

Comment: How do you know it's not accepting any input? Unix password prompts usually don't show what you're typing.

Answer (score 0):

This is standard behaviour. You're probably used to see asterisks (*****) that represent the characters that you type. This is against any security logic because anyone can already see the length of your password, which shouldn't be visible to anyone looking over your shoulder ;)
Unix terminals don't show anything, but they do accept input. If it doesn't accept your password, that's a whole different issue then. If that's the case, open a new thread with as much detail as you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

When using terminal in any Linux Operating System such as Ubuntu, by default it set in such a way that the password typed is not at all visible to the user (not even the asterisks). But you can change this behavior,

1. Open up your terminal (Ctrl-Alt-T).
2. Type the following command:

   $ sudo visudo

   (And for just one more time, also for the last time please type your password wihout getting to see what is being typed).
3. Then scroll down to the line:
   Defaults        env_reset
4. And change it to:
   Defaults        env_reset,pwfeedback
5. Then press Ctrl-X to finish, Y to make changes and Enter to exit.

Now, you will be able to see the asterisks for the typed password in your terminal.